# Hide an axis with a parameter

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a report that uses parameters to hide or show data on a chart at runtime. I have the following code to read the parameter and use it to control the visibility of the axes.

```
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[0].Value);
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[1].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[1].Value);
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[2].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[2].Value);
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[3].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[3].Value);
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[4].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[4].Value);
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[5].View).AxisY.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[5].Value);
```

Because series 0 and series 1 are both tied to the same axis, I am using an or operator. The problem that I am having is that the axis will not hide when they are both false. This is the code that I am using:

```
        bool zero = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[0].Value);
        bool one = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[1].Value);

        if ((zero = true)||(one = true))
        {
            ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = true;

        }

        else if ((zero = false) && (one = false))
        {
            ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = false;
        }
```

How can I get the axis to hide? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If this is C#, and that's actually your code, you want `==` instead of `=` in all your `if` statements.

Comment: That's part of why I prefer the style of just doing `if (zero || one)` and `(!zero && !one)` - it prevents that sort of mistake, and is easier (IMO) to read. Also of note: `zero || one` and `!zero && !one` are opposites; you can just do a plain old `else` and have the same effect. If you want to note what that means, you can do so with a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Tim S. It will make my code a lot cleaner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to remember the difference between equality comparison `==` and the settor operator `=`.  In your `if` statement, you're using the settor, and want to be using the comparison.

If you use the proper operator, your code could look like this, and that should solve your issue:

```
    if ((zero == true)||(one == true))
    {
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = true;

    }
    else if ((zero == false) && (one == false))
    {
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = false;
    }
```

The reason you were having problems is that you were using the settor, which was automatically setting zero and one to true.  Thus, the program was evaluating your `if` statement as: "if (true or true)", which is always true.  This is why setting the values to false wasn't working.

Incidentally, there are a few things you could've done to avoid this mistake.  First, your compiler should have warned you that you weren't using an equality operator.  Second, you could get in the habit of putting constants first: `if (false = zero)` would generate a compile-time error.  (Personally, I really don't like that coding style, it doesn't read cleanly to me, but your mileage may vary.)

I'd rewrite your statements to be a lot cleaner, but functionally equivalent:

```
if (zero || one)
{
    ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = false;
}
```

When you're putting boolean variables in to an if statement, there's no good reason to compare them to boolean constants.  Your second `if` isn't necessary at all, since it's the only case that can happen if the first one doesn't.  (i.e.  "if !(zero || one)" === "!zero && !one" - it's called DeMorgan's Rule.)

In fact, your whole if statement can be condensed down to one clear line:

```
    ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = zero || one;
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem was in using '=' instead of '=='. The expression `zero = true` sets zero to `true` and this `true` value is used as expression value. So, after first condition checking 'zero' always becomes true and 'else' branch never executes because 'zero' is no longer false.

In fact, expression `zero == true` is equal to just `zero`, so you can simplify your condition:

```
    bool zero = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[0].Value);
    bool one = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[1].Value);

    if (zero || one) // true if 'zero' or 'one' is true
    {
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = true;
    }
    else // goes here if both 'zero' and 'one' is false
    {
        ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = false;
    }
```

Or even

```
    bool zero = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[0].Value);
    bool one = Convert.ToBoolean(this.Parameters[1].Value);
    bool axisVisible = zero || one;

    ((SplineSeriesView)xrChart1.Series[0].View).AxisY.Visible = axisVisible;
```

Comment: Thank you for the example and advice.